# Cloudflare SSL not working on AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, cloudflare

I just installed cloudflare on my ec2 instance.

But while opening https://eizo.co.in/ i am getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I've already run a2enmod ssl & apt-get install openssl. Have allocated 443 port.

Please help!

Comment: Hi Arpit, any logs you could provide? Why the site address you posted is important for this?

Comment: @hakamairi the site address I posted is important! because I am getting this issue on this site.

Comment: Have you tried other SSL encrypted sites? And again, any logs?

Comment: It's working fine now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry! It will get fixed automatically just wait for around 24-48 hours.